# Is $\cos(x^2)$ a solution of a 2nd order linear ODE defined on all of $\mathbb R$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been asked in an assignment whether the function $\cos(x^2)$ can be the solution of a 2nd order homogeneous linear equation which satisfies the existence and uniqueness theorem on all of $\mathbb R$. On one hand I cannot find a reason why it wouldn't be a solution of such an equation (unlike $\sin(x^2)$, which was easy) since there is no point where both the function and its derivative vanish, on the other hand I cannot for the life of me find an example of such an equation. Assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut The assignment requested a 2nd order equation, so I'm afraid I cannot use this example.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut $y(0)=1$ here, not $0$. My life would be a lot easier if it was $0$. If it is not possible, I need to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is a solution of $$xy''-y'+4x^3y=0.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this equation does not satisfy the existence and uniqueness theorem on all of $\mathbb R$, which is what was requested, since for example both the trivial solution and $\sin(x^2)$ are solutions of the equation which satisfy $y(0)=y'(0)=0$, so this does not count as an example.

Comment: @Adgorn Every homogeneous equation of second order also has this property. The zero function always trivially satisfies $$Ay''+By'+Cy=0$$ regardless of other solutions.

Comment: You misunderstood me, the problem is not that the zero function is also a solution, which is obvious. The problem is that both it and $\sin(x^2)$ are distinct solutions that have the same initial condition vector at $x=0$, meaning the existence and uniqueness theorem does not hold. I need a 2nd order homogeneous linear equation that, once normalized, all the coefficients are continuous on $\mathbb R$, so that the theorem will hold on all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Adgorn Then you can show that what you are looking for is impossible.